# Force div children text color when specific class is specified

Tags: html, css

I need to override the children color when its parent has specific class.

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
}

.parent>.child {
  color: black;
}

.parent>.child.blue {
  color: blue;
}

.parent.error {
  color: red !important;
}

.parent.error>.child {
  color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Child #1</div>
  <div class="child blue">Child #2</div>
</div>
```

When the parent class is added with "error" using jquery `$('.parent').addClass('error')`, only **Child #1** color changes to red. **Child #2** (which has extra **blue** in its class) `<div class="child blue">Child #2</div>` stays blue.

The question is, how to force **Child #2** to change its color to red without specifying `.parent.error > .child.blue` for error class.

```
/*If this style is added, it will work*/
.parent.error > .child.blue {
    color: red !important;
}
```

Thanks...

Comment: *When the parent class is added with "error" using jquery $('.parent').addClass('error'), only Child #1 color changes to red* --> no, both will change to red so no need to do anything

Comment: Unfortunately, it will not change the color of *Child #2* to red because of `.parent > .child.blue { color: blue; }` (at least not in Chrome). It only worked if I added this style (which I want to avoid) `.parent.error > .child.blue { color: red !important; }`. Vladimir Hala's answer below worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

without deeper brainstorming, my first reaction is:
CSS basic principle says - the more closer a definition is made, the more precedence it gets.

Thus the `!important` part is necessary to make things work.

Alternatively you could re-think the CSS definitions to the opposite ones.
The '.blue' take effect only when the parent's class **does not contain** `.error`.

A fast shot clue - something like this for the **non-errorous case**:

```
.parent:not(.error) > .child.blue {
color: blue; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing! It works perfectly. This is a good compromise. Thanks for that...